# Is there any option to restrict the value of a field with the values of other fields?

Tags: sql

SQL problem.

Imagine this, I got a table with this fields:

- team1
- team2
- winner

Can I do anything to restrict the value of 'winner' to the values of 'team1' OR 'team2'?

(team1 and team2 are foreign fields of a 'Team' table)

So, if I have the teams:

- Real Madrid
- Manchester City
- Juventus

and the match is Real Madrid vs Juventus, I don't want to give the opportunity to put 'Manchester City' in the 'winner' field.

Comment: We need a description of both tables and sample data in order to help you. This is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle database, it can be achieved using CHECK constraint. I am not sure about other databases.

```
CREATE TABLE TAB1
(COL1 NUMBER,
COL2 NUMBER,
COL3 NUMBER
CONSTRAINT CHK1 CHECK (COL3 IN (COL1,COL2) ))
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a553de01c582beab183bef30deb8aa46)

Cheers!!

Comment: The `is null` is not needed because of the way that `check` handles `null` values.

Comment: Appreciated @GordonLinoff. But what happens when col3 will be null?

Comment: . . `check` only fails if the condition is false, not if it is `NULL`.  It differs from `where` and `when` conditions in this respect.

Comment: Correct! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably model it a little differently to enforce the winner using the column structure rather than a constraint or rule.

```
> Create table Teams (   
>   Id integer
>   ,Name varchar(20) );
> 
> Create table Games (
>   HomeTeamId integer
>   ,VisitingTeamId integer  
>   ,HomeTeamWon boolean );
> 
> Insert Into Teams(Id, Name) Values (1, 'Real Madrid'); 
> Insert Into Teams(Id, Name) Values (2, 'Manchester City');
> Insert Into Teams(Id, Name) Values (3, 'Juventus');
> 
> Insert Into Games(HomeTeamId, VisitingTeamId, HomeTeamWon) Values (1,
> 2, True);
> 
> Select
>   HT.Name HomeTeam
>   ,VT.Name VisitingTeam
>   ,Case when HomeTeamWon Then HT.Name Else Vt.Name End WinningTeam 
> From   
>   Games G inner join
>   Teams HT on (G.HomeTeamId = HT.Id) inner join
>   Teams VT on (G.VisitingTeamId = VT.Id)
```

[See in fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/473a0/7)